# is it possible to click a button, while it is moving, using animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
if RainbowLabel.isHidden == true {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.3), animations: {
        self.Red.frame = CGRect(x: self.Red.frame.origin.x, y: self.Red.frame.origin.y - 60 , width: 42, height: 21)
    }) {(finished) in
        if (126 ... 206).contains(self.Red.frame.origin.x) && (45 ... 85).contains      (self.Red.frame.origin.y) {
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Score! Red")
            self.score += 1
            self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.score)
            self.Red0 = 1
            if self.Red0 == 1 && self.Orange0 == 1 && self.Yellow0 == 1 && self.Green0 == 1 && self.Blue0 == 1 && self.Purple0 == 1 {
                self.RainbowLabel.isHidden = true
                self.ResetLabel.isHidden = false
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("15 Points")
                self.score += 15
                self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.score)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like it so this will run, even when Red is moving. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, no. The dirty little secret of iOS animation is that nothing *really* animates. The animation is appearance only. Under the covers, a property immediately snaps to it's end value as soon as the animation begins.

What really happens is that UIView animations are turned into `CAAnimations`, which are done using `CALayers`. A `CALayer` has an optional `presentationLayer` which is drawn on top and updates as an animation progresses.

If you want to make an object tappable while it's animating, you have to put a tap gesture recognizer on the parent view, then use the `CALayer` `hitTest()` method on the presentation layer to see if the tap lands on the view's "in flight" animation.

I have an older project on Github called [**iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo) (written in Objective-C, unfortunately) that illustrates this technique. It does a lot more than that, but it at least shows how you can simulate responding to taps on a view that's being animated. (You'll want to look at the view animation part of that app.)